# WPF style issue on runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, resourcedictionary

I am creating a `ResourceDictionary` file separately and calling it from `App.xaml` file.

Now in my `Window`, I am creating a tree view on rum time. I am allowing the user to add the child at run time.

```
if (strParName == "-1")
{
    treeViewLocation.Items.Clear();
    _nLastAddedNodeID = 0;
    _rootTreeViewItem = newNode;
    strctLocationNode.ParentTreeNode = null;
    treeViewLocation.Items.Add(newNode);
}
    else
    {
        if (localTreeNodeCollection.ContainsKey(strParName))
        {
            parentLocNode = localTreeNodeCollection[strParName];
            parentLocNode.CurrentTreeNode.Focus();
            parentLocNode.CurrentTreeNode.Items.Add(newNode);
        }
    }
```

When I don't apply the `Style`, it works fine. But when I apply the `Style` my code crashes at:

```
parentLocNode.CurrentTreeNode.Focus();
```

Please suggest what should I do?

Comment: What exception it throws ?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: So seems your CurrentTreeNode is null.

Comment: Yes. But when i comment // parentLocNode.CurrentTreeNode.Focus();
It works fine.
But this Focus is required as i need to set the parent.

Comment: You mean CurrentTreeNode is null but still parentLocNode.CurrentTreeNode.Items.Add(newNode); 
works without producing any exception, is it ?

Comment: And what is in `Style`? How did you set?

Comment: It is possible that when you set the `Style`, and then focus on the element, the control is not yet fully rendered (because the `Style`) on to get the focus to it. So it turns out that he return `Null`. In such cases, you need to set the focus to the events of `Loaded` or `Window.ContentRendered`, when all the elements are successfully loaded.